# REMOVE .php with .htaccess cause css error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have used this code on .htaccess as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L,QSA]
```

and it did work. but the page was displayed without css! only html and php was working fine. when I remove .htaccess style would come back on.

what is the problem here?

### UPDATED!

if I inspect the page and went through the head > link (css) and clicked on `style.css` it will display the same html page inside the css page. same goes for jquery file

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess file may need to be placed differently. I placed mine in the root directory and it fixed this issue.

Comment: tried didn't work. see the update.

Answer (score 0):

This will surely help you out, in solving your problem. Here we are appending `.php` to `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` and checking whether it is a file or not, it is then execute the file with `.php` in end.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: it doesn't work. `Object not found!`

Comment: Where are you getting this error and for which file whether is `js` or else.